# Faced Insulation Touching Dryer Vent

Tags: insulation, dryer

Does a dryer vent get hot enough to set faced insulation on fire?

Comment: what type of insulation material is it

Comment: https://www.acehardware.com/departments/building-supplies/insulation-and-house-wrap/insulation/5604814?store=14659&gclid=Cj0KCQjw2MWVBhCQARIsAIjbwoOxh9Mvw3uSKiRRGu7ti0WF_JniVZ-rinWWO7-CcBBoYMXbX4t22KsaAhsBEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: That will not burn, at worst it might melt a little.

Comment: only if  your dryer gets hot enough to set your clothes on fire.

Comment: Distance matters.  The real hot spot is inside of the dryer right beside/behind your clothes.  The vent coming out of the dryer, is almost a foot away, and there might be too hot to touch with skin.  A foot from that spot it will be quite warm to skin.  As long as everything is working well.  A lint or other fire changes things.

Answer (score 1):

No. A fire in a dryer vent is more likely to be due to lint build up.

Answer (score 0):

Your fiberglas does not burn easy, it could melt but at very high temperatures.

Much higher then the dryer went could ever produce.

[image: fiber glas]

It is advisable to clean the vent once in while to remove the lint and improve the air flow

Comment: What about the Kraft paper, faced side of the insulation?

Comment: That one can burn, but let me ask, at what temperature do you run your dryer ?

Comment: On low/medium for the most part.